# Access values with PHP from second table after INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to join two tables on their `id` and then populate an empty array with key - values. `table2` has an additional `city_name` column which I'd like to use.

However, after joining the two tables on their `id` with INNER JOIN, I cannot seem to access the `city_name` value from the second table (but getting the values from the first table works fine).

Here's my code:

```
$city_list = array();
$i = 0;

$q = "SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.city_id";
$res = $mysql_query($q);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res) {
    $city_list[$i]['id'] = $row['id']; // returns the id from table1, which is also identical to the city_id from table2
    $city_list[$i]['population'] = $row['city_population']; // returns the city_population value from table1 
    $city_list[$i]['name'] = $row['city_name']; // returns null, even though the value exists in table2
    $i++;
}
```

When printing the `$city_list`, I get the appropriate `id` and `population` values, but the `name` key has a value of `null`, even though I have city names in `table2`.

Comment: Please post sample data.

Comment: Unsure why your mysql would do that, as `select *` with two tables, will pull all cols in the result set. Easily tested by using mysql command line with that very query you have. If the id's didn't match, it would not be returning any row (since you are doing INNER JOIN).

Comment: The answer has pretty much been provided, but what I don't understand is your table structure.  Are you saying that you need to join 2 tables together only so that you can get the id, population and name of a city?  Why aren't all those attributes in the city table?  What is the other table doing?  You get non-specific answers when you provide non-specific information.  You are also going to have issues with the keys when you fetch data from 2 different tables that both have columns with the same name

Comment: can you post the schema and some sample data of both tables?

Comment: @gview Where did you see columns with same names?

Comment: @Strawberry Too bad many real-world software companies still use them.

Comment: When you do `SELECT table1.*, table2.*` you will get the columns from both tables.  At that point you will probably have a collision.  That is what you need to do to get the city table columns in the result set, as per @Andrew answer.

Comment: @gview Thanks for clearing that out. Please comment this under the provided answer below.

Comment: Which table is `$row['id']` is referring to?

Answer (score 4):

Just select the columns you really need.

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.city_population, table2.city_name 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.city_id
```

Answer (score 2):

You could select the column names using an alias so that you can access both as you want. eg, change query to something like:

```
SELECT *, table2.user_name as table2_user_name 
FROM table1 
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id=table2.city_id
```

Preferably you shouldn't use `*` if you don't need all the data. It tends to lead to more bugs & more difficult maintenance.

Comment: Both queries will return the same result.

Comment: TY for comments changed answer.